# AutoMapper with Array and JsonApiSerializer.JsonApi.Relationship

Tags: arrays, automapper, json-api

I have an AppService solution with the following Classes and i want to map from the SourceObject to the DestinationObject

**Source Classes**

```
 public class SourceObject
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public JsonApiSerializer.JsonApi.Relationship<SourceChildObject[]> childObjects { get; set; }
    }

 public class SourceChildObject
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
    }
```

**Destination Classes**

```
public class DestinationObject
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public JsonApiSerializer.JsonApi.Relationship<DestinationChildObject[]> childObjects { get; set; }
    }

 public class DestinationChildObject
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
    }
```

Auto mapper is setup in the sartup class

```
services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(EntityMappingProfile));
```

And my mapping class loos like this

```
 public class EntityMappingProfile : Profile
    {
        public EntityMappingProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<SourceObject, DestinationObject>();
            CreateMap<Relationship<SourceChildObject[]>, Relationship<DestinationChildObject[]>>();
         }
}
```

When i execute the solution all fields are mapped apart form the array field of type JsonApiSerializer.JsonApi.Relationship. The destination field is null. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You forgot about creating a map between `SourceChildObject` and `DestinationChildObject`. Add this line to your `EntityMappingProfile`.

```cs
CreateMap<SourceChildObject, DestinationChildObject>();
```

And one more thing, when you are mapping generic types, you can enable mapping for all types with:

```cs
CreateMap(typeof(Relationship<>), typeof(Relationship<>));
```

instead of creating a map with concrete use case of a generic type.